# Checked checkbox in React Use Form ignoring value property and always saying "on"

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

No matter what the checkbox value is set to "on" instead of the actual value. I expect the value to be [5], but it is ["on"]

Here is how it's setup:

```
const {
    register,
    watch
} = useForm();

const adPlatformAccountsIds = watch("adPlatformAccountIds")

useEffect(() => {
   console.log(adPlatformAccountsIds) // when checked, I expect this to be [5], but it is ["on"]
}, [adPlatformAccountsIds])
```

Here's the template part:

```
<input className={"checkbox"} type="checkbox" {...register("adPlatformAccountIds", {required: true, })} value={5} />
```

Comment: {...register("example", { value: "5" })} if im not mistaken. been a while